# How to disable Ecmascript 6 linting warnings in Visual Studio Code RC5?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know that this is still a release candidate so it's possible that this functionality doesn't yet exist, but there is a setting for it in the Default Settings:

```
// Specifies which version of ECMA-Script is used.
"javascript.validate.target": "ES5"
```

I tried overwriting this in the User Settings by entering:

```
"javascript.validate.target": "ES6"
```

but this didn't work. Has anyone had any success with this?

Comment: I don't think `"ES6"` is supported yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 is not yet supported by the JavaScript language service in VSCode.

[You can vote for it](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752489-es6-es2015-support), though!

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays this is handled in [jshint options](http://jshint.com/docs/options/), so you should set `jshint.options.esversion` to `6`.

Comment: Creating this entry helped me suppress those older ES version warnings.